# Css align button next to form tag

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How do I align a button next to a html form tag, I am using bootstrap so far I built this:

```
<!-- Wrap all page content here -->
<div id="wrap">

    <!-- Fixed navbar -->
    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                ...
            </div>

            <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <form action="test" method="post" class="navbar-form navbar-right">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Passwort" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Login</button>
                </form>

                // Here I want to add a button                
                <button type="submit"></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The Button which I create after the form should be aligned next to the button inside of the form tag, how do I do this?

Comment: And if you want that button next to the other that is inside the form... why don''t you put the new button inside the form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create your button with the `.navbar-btn` and `.navbar-right` classes e.g. `<button type="button" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn navbar-right">Label</button>`

```
<!-- Wrap all page content here -->
<div id="wrap">

    <!-- Fixed navbar -->
    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                ...
            </div>

            <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <form action="test" method="post" class="navbar-form navbar-right">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Passwort" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Login</button>
            </form>

            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn navbar-right">Sign in</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

PS If you want the button on the right of the form place it before.

Comment: Thanks this worked I placed it before like you mentioned

Answer (score 0):

You can't add `submit` button outside your form. To do this, you will need to :

1) Create `div` inside your `form`with a specific class name, that contains all your `input form` except `submit` button.

2) Then add this in your `CSS` :

```
.<your_new_div_class_form> .<your_class_submit_button> {
    display: inline;
}
```

Comment: I think you are wrong. You can add a submit button outside a form and reference the form you want to submit with the attribute form.(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button)

Comment: Yes, it is doable with JS, I didn't specify it. Except that, the answer I post should do the trick.

Comment: You can do it with JS, but there is no need for it. Check the attribute 'form' in the link sent in my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add the class `.btn` (and the class `.btn-{level}` you need) to the `<button>` element.

Comment: My bad. Its like Aeberhard said: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-buttons

Answer (score 0):

You can just add button inside form tag itself and give it a type as button and implement functionality in javascript onClick

```
    <div id="wrap">

    <!-- Fixed navbar -->
    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                ...
            </div>

            <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">

                <form action="test" method="post" class="navbar-form navbar-right">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Passwort" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Login</button>
                    <button type="button" value="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="doSOmething();" >OK</button>
                </form>



            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the button needs to be outside of the form tag

Comment: Then you can put form inside **col-md-10** and button inside **col-md-2** and both form and button inside **row**. See it in action https://jsfiddle.net/689vvy55/